# python pydev and raspberryPi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pydev

I made some code using Pydev, python.

codes worked well and resulted good.

but when I run it on the raspberryPi, errors occurred and it didn't work well.  Of course, I couldn't get proper results..

```
print ser.readline()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'readline'

File "gpste.py", line 103, in sav_loc
    line = str(location.address)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

what's the problem??

and when i insert Ctrl+c, it didn't work. why and how can I stop the program in the middle of process??

Comment: Looks like you forgot to put readline function in the directory where you're executing.

Answer (score 0):

You are having two problems here.

1. It seems like you overloaded `ser` with an integer. For details we need more code.
2. `location.address` does not have the right encoding. Again to say more we would need the code and content of `location.address`.